# How to get scroll while using DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I'm new in GWT and uiBinder, and I need to display a scroll when the window is reduced in order to display items that have a fixed size.

**UiBinder.xml**

```
<clui:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
        <clui:center>
          <clui:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="2" barUnit="EM" width="100%" height="100%" ui:field="tabs" />
        </clui:center>   
</clui:DockLayoutPanel>
```

**Java code**

```
@UiField TabLayoutPanel tabs;

interface IndexUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Index> {
}

public doc() {
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

  tabs.add(new FirstDoc(), "First");
  tabs.add(new SecondDoc(), "Second");
}
```

I've try to add property to the css, the scroll appears, but not working

```
body {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ScrollPanel. You add it (and only it!) to your tab, then everything else goes inside the ScrollPanel.

Comment: Thanks, I've to add scrollPanel for each tab? Because I tried this but not working: ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel(tabs);

Comment: You'd have to add the ScrollPanel in between the DockLayoutPanel and the TabLayoutPanel, or between the TabLayoutPanel and each of the tab's widget (e.g. `tabs.add(new ScrollPanel(new FirstDoc()), "First")`)

Comment: Typically, you add a ScrollPanel inside of each tab (as Thomas suggested), so that the tab always remains visible, while the contents of a tab scrolls when necessary.

Comment: @Thomas, when I add the scrollPanel, the content of the tab is blanck.

Comment: Maybe I've to add ScrollPanel to the uiBinder xml?

Comment: You can add it in UiBinder. Which code are you using?